# Windows 10 explorer.exe crash when networkdrive is not reachable

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-explorer, crash

I have some Win 10 Clients (1909) with network drives mapped. I have my office Wi-Fi where the network drives are reachable. Now everything is fine and works normally. 
When a client is disconnecting the office Wi-Fi and switching to guest network (also Wi-Fi) and I want to access a folder in my network drive (because I forgot that I'm in the guest Wi-Fi) my explorer.exe stops working and crashes after a while. Only way to fix this is to restart the explorer.exe from task manager.

My first try was that some extensions like the Antivirus are the reason for that issue, so I uninstalled everything but without success. The issue still exist. It looks like the Explorer.exe is waiting and a timeout is not working. I never get the message that the resource is not available.

Anyone heard about an issue like that?

Comment: I have the same issue, you ever find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue between the emc storage and Windows. We think thst emc haven't implemented the protocol well. Our solution was to route all fileshares over a Windows dfs server. Works well now